# Accessing Jira 4.4.5 via JSON-RPC on localhost http port

Tags: python, jira, json-rpc

I am trying to get access to a local JIRA 4.4.5 installation using it's JSON-RPC service. Therefore I wrote a python script utilizing jsonrpclib and trying to connect to `http://localhost:8080/jira/rpc/json-rpc/jirasoapservice-v2`​ as described on https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/JIRA+JSON-RPC+Overview. Trying to connect from my python script as well as opening this URL in a browser gives me a 404 error.

```
import jsonrpclib
server = jsonrpclib.Server("http://localhost:8080/jira/rpc/json-rpc/jirasoapservice-v2")
reply = server.someMethod( param1, ... )
```

Calling `someMethod` fails with the following error:

```
xmlrpclib.ProtocolError: <ProtocolError for localhost:8080/jira/rpc/json-rpc/jirasoapservice-v2: 404 Not Found>
```

Has anyone successfully tried this the same way I did? Do I need to get access via HTTPS somehow instead of HTTP? How would I configure jira to do so?

Btw: Jira's json-rpc plugin is enabled.